# Rails: handling errors within respond_to block (csv)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a search method on my controller that responds to either the html or CSV format. The html format renders the search results as expected, and I want the CSV format to work by downloading a CSV file of the results.

Most of the time, `send_data` is called and the CSV file is generated. However there are situations in which I **don't** want to generate the CSV, and instead show an error (for example when a user has used all of their allotted exports for the month). The following code is a simplified version of what I'd *like* to do, however this doesn't seem to like how I'm attempting to handle the error.

```
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
         @results = ...
         render "index"
      end

      format.csv do
        @results = ...

        if user_can_export?(@results)
          send_data generate_csv(@results), filename: "Search-Results.csv"
        else
          flash[:error] = "Unable to export search results."
          render "index"
        end
      end
    end
```

Is there any way for me to break out of this block and render HTML or am I stuck generating a csv file here? I'd prefer to not handle this situation by sending a csv file with an error message contained in it, but that seems like my best option at the moment. Help is appreciated!

Comment: the `.` after  `"Unable to export search results"` will lead to an error.

Comment: good catch. this isnt at all the real code though, just something I typed up to give an idea. I fixed the typo above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the content-type header to  `text/html` instead of  `text/csv`.

```
render template: "things/index.html.erb", content_type: "text/html"
```

Also if you want to display a flash message in the current request cycle you need to use `flash.now[:error] = "Unable to export search results"`

Comment: Still getting a missing template error. Seems like its still trying to use the csv format:

`Missing template vulnerabilities/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:csv], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :rabl]}.`

Comment: Ah, you need to use an explicit path to the template. `render template: "things/index.html.erb"`

Comment: It looks for the wrong template because rails is still treating the request as CSV. You could possibly solve it by using `content_type  = "text/html"` which   I believe alters the response object so that i would use `html` for the template lookup.

Comment: explicitly calling the template does work (although I get unrelated errors because I'm missing instance variable required for that template).
I also found that adding `formats: [:html]` worked to change the format in the previous scenario. Thanks for your help.